# Template not getting rendered on django

Tags: python, html, django

views.py file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('upload/testpage.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render)
```

app/templates/app/testpage.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px" multiple />
    <a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('upload').click(); return false">Upload</a>
</body>
</html>
```

app/urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),]
```

project/urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^upload/', include('upload.urls')),]
```

Getting an error when running file on local server 127.0.0.1:8000/app of "TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/"

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Seems that your template is located in "app" folder not in "upload" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app/testpage.html')
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

With your current file path `app/templates/app/testpage.html` this one should works

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('app/testpage.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render)
```

Another way to do it is to change your template path to `app/templates/upload/testpage.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not create any **upload** folder inside **templtes** folder. 
If you have **app** folder like that

> `app/templates/app/testpage.html`

Now, you can fix it

```
template = loader.get_template('app/testpage.html')
```